# What i need Development or Production Push SSL Certificate in APNs?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I want to activate Apple Push notification service in my application and this application which i am building is for client, and i don't know that how many client will be further use this application or installed on how many devices, so i am little confuse that what i actually need Development or production Push SSL certificate?

Comment: The APNS ssl cert is for the server that is generating the push notifications.  How many servers will generate the push notifications?  Apple provides two servers -- Production and Development -- so you can test your code with the Development server without bothering your Production server.

Comment: Also note that apple now supports connection to Development servers with production certificates.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Follow [APNS-Development push SSL or Production push SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396240/apns-development-push-ssl-or-production-push-ssl)

Step by Step SetUp for pushNotification

[How to Configure & Send Apple Push Notifications using PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp)