# APNS-Development push SSL or Production push SSL?

Tags: iphone, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

I want to create an application with apple push notification services. I have used Development Push SSL at the development time and I have done the app and all the testing, and its working fine. So now I want to distribute the app through appstore. So which one should i use? Development push SSL or Production push SSL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to setup and use the **Production Certificates** for app store releases.

See the [**`iOS Provisioning Portal`**](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/index.action), App ID's, then configure your certificates for Production.

[image]

Then download and use this Production certificate to sign your apps that you want to submit to the App Store.

[image]

Comment: i have created a new appid and a certificate Enabled for production. So should i make this Enabled for Development also?

Comment: 1 app id should allow for a development certificate and a production certificate. You can download both of these and use them to sign your app. When you want to submit your app to the app store, use the production certificate generated for push notifications.